# Use Sling taglib in GSP script

Tags: groovy, gsp, sling

I'm trying to use the Sling taglib in a GSP script but I get this error when importing it:

```
10.11.2015 10:02:41.392 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1447146161196] GET /com/test/networks/network_a.html HTTP/1.1]      org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
GStringTemplateScript1.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class taglib ,  unable to find class for annotation
 @ line 2, column 53.
 eturn { out -> out << """"""; @taglib pr
                             ^

1 error
```

The script's first line is:

```
<%@taglib prefix="sling" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling" %>
```

I've installed Groovy 2.2.4 and I see it in Felix console (Script Engines)

```
Available Script Engines
========================

Groovy Scripting Engine 2.0
-------------------------------------
- Language : Groovy, 2.4.5
- Extensions : groovy
- MIME Types : application/x-groovy
- Names : groovy, Groovy

GSPScriptEngineFactory 0
-------------------------------------
- Language : Groovy Scripting Pages, 1.0
- Extensions : gsp
- MIME Types : -
- Names : gsp, GSP
```

This bundle is installed and started:

```
Apache Sling JSP Tag Library org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib
```

Am I missing something? I looked at the available documentation and tried to find examples but didn't find a lot.

I have also tried with JDK 1.8 and 1.7, same result.

### EDIT

After Robert's comment I've realized that this bundle wasn't actually installed and started, even though with groovy-all.jar I could see GSP in the Script Engines: https://github.com/sling-git/sling/tree/master/contrib/scripting/groovy

There is another repository here: https://github.com/sling-git/org.apache.sling.scripting.groovy

But I've built and installed it and now in the console for this bundle I see:

```
Apache Sling Scripting Groovy Support (org.apache.sling.scripting.groovy)
Symbolic Name   org.apache.sling.scripting.groovy

Imported Packages   groovy.json,version=2.4.5 from groovy-all (124)
                  groovy.lang,version=2.4.5 from groovy-all (124)
                  groovy.text,version=2.4.5 from groovy-all (124)
                  javax.script,version=0.0.0.1_008_JavaSE from org.apache.felix.framework (0)
                  org.apache.sling.commons.classloader,version=1.3.0 from org.apache.sling.commons.classloader (84)
                  org.apache.sling.scripting.api,version=2.3.0 from org.apache.sling.scripting.api (107)
```

Comment: I suspect that the GSPScriptEngineFactory needs to access the classes from the org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib bundle, but it can't. Can you update the question with the packages which are imported by the bundle holding the GSPScriptEngineFactory ?

Comment: Hello Robert, thank you, I've added the list.